# Want to fetch the value - "In Progress" from the below mentioned html code

Tags: javascript

Want to fetch the value - "In Progress" from the below mentioned html code

```
<span id="status-val" class="value">
<span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-yellow jira-issue-status-lozenge-indeterminate jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-title&quot;&gt;In Progress&lt;/span&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;span class=&quot;jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc&quot;&gt;This issue is being actively worked on at the moment by the assignee.&lt;/span&gt;">In Progress</span></span>
```

Comment: <span id="status-val" class="value">
<span class=" jira-issue-status-lozenge aui-lozenge jira-issue-status-lozenge-yellow jira-issue-status-lozenge-indeterminate 
jira-issue-status-lozenge-max-width-medium" data-tooltip="<span class="jira-issue-status-tooltip-title">In Progress</span><br>
<span class="jira-issue-status-tooltip-desc">This issue is being actively worked on at the moment by the assignee.</span>" original-title="">In Progress</span> 
 </span>

Comment: This is invalid markup!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.getElementsByClassName` for this purpose. It returns a collection of elements, so you need to access it like

```
document.getElementsByClassName('jira-issue-status-lozenge')[0].innerHTML
```